# Change the scale of Slider

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using the Slider component of Xamarin Form, but I need to select a time from the slider. How can I change the scale of the slider from 100 to 60 .

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation for slider? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Slider/

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Maximum` property like this:

```xml
<Slider Maximum="60" Minimum="0" Value="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```